# Haskell Inaccessible code bug?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, gadt

Say I have the following (erroneous) code.

```
data A a b where
  APure ::  (A a b)
  AApply :: A (A b c) c

test :: (A a b) -> a -> b
test (APure) a = a
test AApply a = undefined
```

GHC will then give me this error:

```
Couldn't match type `b' with `A b1 b'
  `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for test :: A a b -> a -> b
Inaccessible code in
  a pattern with constructor
    AApply :: forall c b. A (A b c) c,
  in an equation for `test'
In the pattern: AApply
In an equation for `test': test AApply a = undefined
```

Isn't this error message completely wrong?
The error has nothing to do with AApply.

Comment: How is `AApply` supposed to have the general type `A a b` if you declare it as `A (A b c) c` already? It's like if you were defining `concat' :: [a] -> [b]` as `concat' = concat`: how is Haskell going to unify `a` "down" to `[b]`?.

Comment: Yes, it's unintuitive. Perhaps you should [file a bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/newticket?type=bug).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I do not really understand what you mean, but that case is entierlly correct. Read up on patternmatching with GADTs.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov, I'll do that

Comment: Yeah right, I was confused by the absence of data fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't this error message completely wrong? The error has nothing to do with `AApply`.

Not completely. It's arguably a bug that you get that error message, but it's not completely off base.

Look at the whole thing together after looking at the pieces.

```
test (APure) a = a
```

says we have a function

```
test :: A a b -> r -> r
```

Put that together with the signature

```
test :: (A a b) -> a -> b
```

and unify, ignoring the type error from the first equation, the type is refined to

```
test :: A r r -> r -> r
```

Then look at the equation

```
test AApply a = undefined
```

and see how that is inaccessible under the refined type, since

```
AApply :: A (A b c) c
```

would entail

```
c ~ A b c
```

if `AApply` were a valid first argument.

Comment: I suspected something like this happened. Why does it unify to `A r r -> r -> r`? How can the type change to something else when the type of the function is specified?

Comment: With GADTs, you get type refinement. I think what happens here is a bug in the type-checker (and with 6.12.3, you get the unsurprising ``Couldn't match expected type `b' against inferred type `a'`` for the first equation; 7.0, 7.2 and 7.4 give only the error for the second equation; 7.6 both) - resp. the error-message producer, refinement gone awry. It should have stopped on the error in the first equation. But once it continued after that, it worked with inconsistent hypotheses, so it isn't too surprising that it ends with a silly result.

Comment: Oh, so it is a bug that is fixed (but my GHC version is to old). Thanks!