# Enabling "-fno-warn-" for Inaccessible code in GADTs

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt, deriving

Given a `GADT` indexed by a phantom variable I can use standalone deriving to create some simple instances

```
data Client
data Temporary
data Permanent

data Token ty where
  ClientToken :: Token Client
  TemporaryToken :: ByteString -> ByteString -> Token Temporary
  PermanentToken :: ByteString -> ByteString -> Token Permanent

deriving instance Eq (Token Client)
deriving instance Eq (Token Temporary)
deriving instance Eq (Token Permanent)
```

which appear to work perfectly in GHCi

```
> ClientToken == ClientToken
True
> TemporaryToken "" "foo" == TemporaryToken "" "bar"
False
```

When I try to compile I get a warning, though.

```
src/Network/HTTP/Conduit/OAuth/Types/Credentials.hs:72:1:
    Couldn't match type `Client' with `Temporary'
    Inaccessible code in
      a pattern with constructor
        TemporaryToken :: S8.ByteString
                          -> S8.ByteString -> Token Temporary,
      in an equation for `=='
    In the pattern: TemporaryToken a1 a2
    In an equation for `==':
        == (TemporaryToken a1 a2) (TemporaryToken b1 b2)
          = (((a1 == b1)) && ((a2 == b2)))
    When typechecking the code for  `=='
      in a standalone derived instance for `Eq (Token Client)':
      To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
    In the instance declaration for `Eq (Token Client)'
```

Which seems to be a buggy bit of the GADT deriving code (re: [Haskell Inaccessible code bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134836/haskell-inaccessible-code-bug) and https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8128) but since it seems to have the right behavior I'd like to know

1. Can I turn off these warnings with some `-fno-warn-*` flag? And, if possible
2. Is there any problematic side effect to doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your example code in GHC 7.6.3 and at least there I get an actual compilation *error* instead of a warning in both GHCi and when compiling. It seems that the automatic instance deriving isn't smart enough to realize that it only needs to match a single constructor with the given GADT.

The following works though

```
data Client
data Temporary
data Permanent

data Token ty where
  ClientToken :: Token Client
  TemporaryToken :: ByteString -> ByteString -> Token Temporary
  PermanentToken :: ByteString -> ByteString -> Token Permanent

deriving instance Eq (Token ty)
```

But maybe your real use-case is more complex?

Comment: Hm, it is, but I think I can play around with it to get that functional. I also realized mine were errors, too, but I confused them due to `-Wall`. That is probably the right "answer" to my questions. I'll try rearranging my actual code and probably accept this.